# Is it possible to encode/decode all urls with spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So I have a Spring Application with a React project. Im doing some test and I have requests that envole url parameters. For example:

`http://localhost:8080/rest/user/{user email}`

Now I dont want to make these emails public so i thought about either encoding them into base64 or just encrypt them using AES or something of the sort. Doing it in react is quite simple, but can I do it with Spring? I mean short of running every url parameter through a decrypt function?
Something like a filter that basically decrypts the url or something like that?

Comment: I'm sure there is a reasonable use case for it, but that is the trouble with using natural keys, versus non-natural ones.  My instinct would be first to see if I could identify my user resource by an non-natural id.

Comment: I mean i did that by using uuids, but people that try to find users can't do it via uuid search right?

Comment: If your app is a porn or a dating site for married men, and the email was how you identified them, i would not use the email out in the open to identify and get their user record, eg. their account.  But if that {user email} value is a query looking for a user with that email I would, personally, 
a) make that a query param, because that is what it is and b) not worry about obfuscation.